# Measuring privacy policy

Tags: privacy, corporate-policy

I want to measure if the user's data which is collected by the system is mentioned in the privacy policy.

What is the best measure that I can use it in such case?

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your question?

Comment: You will need to review the data collected and compare this to the privacy policy. If you can afford to hire an consultant, they'll probably do a good job. Voting to close your question.

Comment: Are you the owner of the system or the owner of the data? Does the Privacy Policy define what is private data? Does the system define what is private data upon collection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need more information to give you a better answer. But in general you need to work out what information you want, why you want it and what local laws, regulations and guidelines you have to be compliant with. Then document and produce a report on the conclusions of this process.

Once you have done that, you should perform a full audit of your systems, the information you are currently collecting and how you are storing that information. Then align it with the documentation from phase one.

Here are a couple of handy links to point you in the right direction;

[Guidelines for Online Privacy Policies](http://www.privacyalliance.org/resources/ppguidelines/)

[Guide to data protection](https://ico.org.uk/for-organisations/guide-to-data-protection/)